# Is there a Purescript typeclass generalizing integers?

Tags: integer, typeclass, purescript

Haskell has the [`Integral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) typeclass which includes `Integer`, `Int`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Natural`, etc.

Is there a similar typeclass in Purescript?

Comment: [Harry Garrood's A Guide to the PureScript Numeric Hierarchy](https://a-guide-to-the-purescript-numeric-hierarchy.readthedocs.io) seems to be a generalized (and expanded) version of the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't have any integer-specific classes in PureScript, but there is a hierarchy of numeric classes:

[image: Numeric hierarchy]

Each class adds laws, so although the `CommutativeRing` and `Field` classes have no operations they are not redundant.

Any type that is a `EuclideanRing` also satisfies the laws for integral domains, which generalise integers, so I think that should suit your needs.

`Fields` have non-zero multiplicative inverses: `mod a b = 0` for all `a` and `b`, so using that constraint would rule out the possibility of integer division, etc. if that's what you're looking for, so you definitely don't want to that far down the hierarchy.